# Is there a way to rename "Remaining" to "Apple Juice Remaining"?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, menu-bar

On a MacBook Pro, is there a way to change the text in the battery life drop down?

Specifically, where it says "X:XX Remaining" I want it to say "X:XX of Apple Juice Remaining"

Why? Because a good pun is its own reword.

Yes, this is a serious question.  Yes, I tried googling first.

I'm currently running Mavericks, though an upgrade to Yosemite is probably in my near future.

Comment: "Because a good pun is its own reword." *groan*

Comment: You forgot to modify "Power Source" from "Battery" to "300mL Apple Juice Box". You could also change "charger" for "refilling machine".

Comment: I actually went back in and made some additional modifications after I posted that picture, though I didn't think of "Apple Juice Box/Apple Juice Dispenser" as power sources.  haha

Comment: Thats funny! :D

Comment: I signed up just to point out that this is the exact reason us non-Apple users hate you all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You mean because Apple-users think this is funny, or because Apple-users can actually do this?

Comment: Oh, I'd upvote this, but it's sitting at exactly 64! (:

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You want to change line 92 of the xml version of  `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings`:

1. Make a copy of the strings file:

   ```
   cp /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/Battery.menu/Contents/Resources/\
   English.lproj/Localizable.strings ~/Desktop
   ```
2. Convert the binary strings file to xml:

   ```
   plutil -convert xml1 ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings
   ```
3. Edit line 92 (Yosemite) of the file now on the desktop with your favourite text editor:

   [image]
4. Convert the xml strings file back to binary:

   ```
   plutil -convert binary1 ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings
   ```
5. Back up your existing file! If you mess up, this will let you reverse your changes by removing -bak from the file name.

   ```
   sudo mv /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/Battery.menu/Contents/Resources/\
   English.lproj/Localizable.strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/\
   Battery.menu/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings-bak
   ```
6. Overwrite the old file with the new:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/Desktop/Localizable.strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/\
   Battery.menu/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/
   ```

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: You sir are a genius.

Comment: I was wondering how you'd be pulling this off, but of course - locales! Nice.

Comment: Very nice solution.  Note that for me the line numbers weren't the same, but it being a simple xml file it wasn't exactly difficult to track down the keys that needed to be changed.  I took it further and changed other parts of the dialog text as well.  Thanks for indulging my sense of humor :)

Comment: Also: +1 for inserting the backup step, though it should probably be spelled out that you did so (users that stumble across this via google might not pick up on it)

Comment: Something's missing from your instructions--I don't see anything in there about backing up your System file before you open ResEdit.

Comment: Does this procedure work in El Capitan?

Comment: @user24601 Yes, if you disable System Integrity Protection.